# Running VB code in 64 bit Machine

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dll

I am trying to debug an application in Microsoft Visual Basic. This application uses third party tools like UltraTool Bar, Active Thread, XtremeSuite etc. Some of these tools used, might be for 32 Bit. When I try running the application from code it crashes before loading WinForm. I checked for the exception in event viewer I am getting the below message.

```
 <Data>Application: vb6.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException at <Module>.CVPCServiceMgr.{ctor}(CVPCServiceMgr*) at <Module>.?A0x1119eba0.??__Eg_oServiceMgr@@YMXXZ() at <Module>._initterm_m(Void* ()*, Void* ()*) at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.InitializePerProcess(<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport*) at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport*) at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport*) Exception Info: <CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadException at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport*) at <Module>..cctor() Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException</Data>
```

Is this issue related to running 32 applications on 64 bit machine?

Comment: ====> FileNotFoundException. Try using ProcessMonitor from sysinternals

Comment: Does this 3rd party requires to be registered? If it is a COM, you need to run regsvr32 on it

Comment: You have a global variable named `g_oServiceMgr` in a C++/CLI assembly.  It is initialized when that assembly is loaded, it needs other DLL(s) to make that work. This happens very early, too early to do anything to help find that DLL.  And very little hope to find that DLL since the code runs inside VB6.exe.  A temporary workaround is to copy all the DLLs into the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB6 directory.  Pretty clunky but good enough to get the code debugged.  Getting rid of initialized global variables should be a goal.

Comment: I need to copy DLL(s) from which path. C:\Windows\SysWow64\ this path I'll chose or I have to include DLLs of the 3rd party tools also.